# Find line with phraseA or phraseB exclude phraseC using RegEx

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm analyzing log file using regular expression in Notepad++. I need to find lines that contains phraseA or phraseB, but excludes phraseC.

expression below works fine

```
phraseA|phraseB
```

now I need exclude phraseC

```
phraseA|phraseB^phraseC
```

but this does't works. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
^(?!.*?phraseC).*?phrase[AB]
```

The first construct `(?!.*?phraseC)` is a negative lookahead to make sure the line doesn't contain `phraseC`.

The second part of the expression `.*?phrase[AB]` makes sure there is a `phraseA` or `phraseB`.